# MySQL: Lessons booked in the last 12 months grouped by teacher

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables of teachers  and lessons in an online tuition center, like below:

Teachers Table:

```
+----+--------+
| id |name    | 
+----+--------+ 
| 1  | John   | 
| 2  | Mike   | 
| 3  | Bill   | 
+----+--------+
```

Lessons Table:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| id | booking_time       | teacher   | student  |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | 2017-08-08 12:00:00| 3         | 40       |
| 2  | 2017-10-03 12:00:00| 1         | 50       |
| 3  | 2017-12-01 12:00:00| 2         | 60       |
| 4  | 2018-01-01 12:00:00| 3         | 40       |
| 5  | 2018-02-01 12:00:00| 2         | 60       |
| 6  | 2018-03-02 12:00:00| 3         | 40       |
| 7  | 2018-03-04 12:00:00| 1         | 50       |
| 8  | 2018-03-06 12:00:00| 1         | 50       |
+----+--------------------+-----------+----------+
```

I need to get each teacher's total booked lessons in the last 12 months (starting from current month) and sorted by the current month's highest bookings. Something like:

```
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+
|Teacher|Mar-18|Feb-18|Jan-18|Dec-17|Nov-17|Oct-17|Sep-17|Aug-17|Jul-17| Jun-17|May-17|Apr-17|
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+
|John   |2     |0     |0     |0     |0     |1     |0     |0     |0     |0      |0     |0     |
|Bill   |1     |0     |1     |0     |0     |0     |0     |1     |0     |0      |0     |0     |
|Mike   |0     |1     |0     |1     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0      |0     |0     | 
+-------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+
```

Any help how I can do this please?

Comment: what is your version of mySql? Thanks.

Comment: Mysql version is 5.5